# Java OOP, How can I design a class with many list type fields to a single class?

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, uml, relational-database

I have a class with many fields of type List<> because I need to save a log history for every change. For example:

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private List<Log> name;
    private List<Log> lastname;
    private List<Log> phone;
}

public class Log {
    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private User user;
    private String content;
}
```

So, every time a user make an update, it will be saved on log table. The problem is I don't know how to make the relationship between them. I'm using hibernate.
And that is only Student class, but I have about 10 more classes with the same scenario.

Is there a better way to do that? maybe a pattern design?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/

Comment: Where is the relation to UML here?

Answer (score 1):

From a design standpoint, I would prefer to have a versioned Student table, with a timestamp for each version.  Then you can easily determine what lastName and firstName were at a given point in time.

Hibernate supports a few different approaches to this as well.

Comment: Check out section 5.1.11 in the hib docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-timestamp